# Is it possible to give a fair assessment of the influence of Bourbaki's "Eléments de mathématique"?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

Well, I apologize  if this "soft-question" (related to the "**Arnold-Serre**" debate) is considered as irrelevant for MO, and for possible misunderstandings in the two earlier versions of this post (which was not provocative).

I certainly do **not** want to stir a useless debate. As a french math teacher, I know that Henri Cartan, Claude Chevalley, Jean Dieudonné, Charles Ehresmann, Jean-Pierre Serre, André Weil ... were all great mathematicians. Obviously, N. Bourbaki had a huge impact on the mathematics of the last century. I'm also well aware of his predominance on french mathematics, but I know virtually nothing about his influence on others mathematical schools.

So I do believe that the following question is not really "opinion-based" (question which is **not** about the present production  of the very much alive Bourbaki seminar) :

**Question** : Is it now possible to give a fair assessment of the influence of Bourbaki's "**Eléments de mathématique**" ?

(I'm ready to accept the answer : "No, it's impossible").

Comment: Died 1968??????

Comment: Bourbaki did not die in 1968. They published a book recently and organize a seminar.

Comment: The problem with the way you formulate the question is that Bourbaki never published a research paper or book. So the question is a little bit like: what the mathematical importance of wikipedia ? If the question is to be understood "how useful are Bourbaki's books for a research mathematician, as compared say, with wikipedia?", then it may make some sense... Also, what happened in 1968 regarding to Bourbaki?

Comment: @Joël there is some annoucement of the death of Bourbaki from 1968 written by Roubaud, in the context of OuLiPo. Details should be handy online.

Comment: My understanding is that Oulipo (if I may be permitted to personify it, in keeping with how Bourbaki is personified) has an impish sense of humor. It's not clear to me that his scholarship is impeccable. :-)

Comment: I find this is broad and subjective, as it stands.

Comment: @Joël Of course, the Bourbaki seminar (amphi Hermite, IHP, Paris) is still going on, Serre, Cartier and Grothendieck are living, but I thought that the Bourbakist prank

Comment: @Joël I'm sorry for the bad editing. Of course, I'm well aware the the Bourbaki seminar (amphi Hermite, IHP, Paris) is still going on, and that at least Serre, Cartier and Grothendieck are still living, but I thought that the Bourbakist prank http://math.univ-angers.fr/~darniere/bourbaki.html#deces was more widely known, so my feeble attempt at humour failed miserably. Yes, my question is broad, and no, it is not subjective. I have a strong personal opinion, and I would like to read a truly unbiaised assessment, but you can close my question immediately

Comment: On my opinion their influence was enormous, and I do not see why this question was closed. It is no more "subjective" then other soft questions.

Comment: Your remark on Serre, Cartier, Grothendieck is a bit besides the point. You can find various other *former* memebers, but a lot younger than the ones you mentioned, on http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki towards the end

Comment: @Smaug, I was not for closing. I think I knew about the faire-part de décès, but had completely forgotten. It's fun. But still, the question seems to me a little ill-defined. What is Bourbaki? Is it just the author of the book signed Bourbaki, or is it the sum of its members? In the second case, there is no doubt that mathematical importance of Bourbaki was overwhelming, but I think you meant it more in the first sense. But then the question has a different meaning: how influential Bourbaki was as a teacher, as a text-book author? In this sense as well, the obvious answer is "enormous":

Comment: Indeed, it suffices to consider the influence of Bourbaki on his own members (Cartan, Serre, Grothendieck, etc.) with by their own account is fundamental, and the contribution of those members to mathematics.

Comment: I did not close it either, but I think the issue is that the request for "imortance" here is not meant as asking if the influence on the history of mathematics was "big" or "small" (that seems completely obvious) but if it was "good" or "bad" (where opinion might come into play). And that the post is a bit provocative does not help.

Comment: Bourbaki disbanded when they realized that Serge Lang is just one person.

Comment: @Joël: According to MathSciNet, Bourbaki wrote three research papers (and two papers that might be deemed surveys).

Comment: @ Joël and @quid : I agree that my question was not initially well formulated, and the second version is (maybe) more precise, but, no, my first post was not provocative. Of course, Bourbaki's impact on the mathematical world was very great, I was simply asking if it is now possible to weight fairly its positive and negative aspects. Since everybody seems to consider that it is an "opinion-based" question, the answer is probably a resounding "NO".

Comment: Thanks for the edit. First, the writing of Éléments de mathématique seems neither completed nor finished, either; but this is perhaps nit-picking. Second, and more importantly, while your comment is rather clear regarding what you want  now, yout post is still not clear regarding this. Regarding the simple "no" as answer. Yes, this! :-) I even had a comment typed saying just this earlier, but thought it might be considered as dismissive. And thus did not post it.

Comment: @quid Thanks for considering it as "potentially" dismissive.

Comment: There is a serious attempt to assess the influence of what Bourbaki proposed as the central concept of the entire Elements corpus, namely that of *Structure*, by Leo Corry: http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/bourbaki-structures.html. It can be argued, for various reasons, that this concept did not "take". On the other hand, we have the masterly Lie Groups and Lie Algebras which really set a standard for generations. So it seems to me an assessment of the influence of the Elements might best proceed on a book-by-book basis.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for the reference, a very interesting read.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Well, thanks, I appreciate your answer.